# How to pass keys as a list of strings to D3 group?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

The [`d3.group`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/main/README.md#group) documentation says:

```
d3.group(iterable, ...keys)
```

For example, if I have the following:

```
data = [
  {name: "jim",   amount: "34.0",   date: "11/12/2015"},
  {name: "carl",  amount: "120.11", date: "11/12/2015"},
  {name: "stacy", amount: "12.01",  date: "01/04/2016"},
  {name: "stacy", amount: "34.05",  date: "01/04/2016"}
]
```

But instead of:

```
d3.group(data, d => d.name, d => d.date)
```

I want to do something like:

```
d3.group(data, ['name', 'date'])
```

How should I do it? The reason is that I might not know the keys in advance and will have to do the grouping programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`...keys` can be a `map` which itself returns a function e.g. `...keys.map(k => d => d[k])`.

See below - this uses `groups` instead of `group` as it's readable in the console output - but this works for `group` as well.

```js
const data = [
  {name: "jim",   amount: "34.0",   date: "11/12/2015"},
  {name: "carl",  amount: "120.11", date: "11/12/2015"},
  {name: "stacy", amount: "12.01",  date: "01/04/2016"},
  {name: "stacy", amount: "34.05",  date: "01/04/2016"}
];

const keys = ["name", "date"];

const grps = d3.groups(
  data,
  ...keys.map(k => d => d[k])
);

console.log(grps);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.6.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```